# Unable to create/view SQLite database in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to create an SQLite database for my app in Androis Studio 2.3.

I have tried the following-

**Approach-1:** Created a class extending from `SQLiteOpenHelper` and overriding `OnCreate`

```
public AppDB(Context context){
    super(context, DBName, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " (RecordingID TEXT PRIMARY KEY,RecordItemName TEXT,RecordFilePath TEXT,RecordFileDate TEXT)");
}
```

**Approach-2:** Tried adding these two lines in my Main activity's `OnCreate`

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("AppDB.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Recordings (RecordingID TEXT PRIMARY KEY,RecordItemName TEXT,RecordFilePath TEXT,RecordFileDate TEXT)");
```

My app launches fine on emulator. When I try to verify the created database using Android Device Monitor > File Manager, I can't see my database under the *data* folder.
[image]
I am very new to Android and can't figure what am I doing wrong. Please tell me if I can add more details on this.

Comment: You have to use DDMS in order to see your database Instructions are here https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

Comment: which Api are you targeting?is your device a real device or an AVD?

Comment: @Hank I have added an image. From the link you provided I think they are doing something similar

Comment: @MiladMoosavi API 25 on Nexus-4 emulator

Answer (score 1):

Due to permission issues after Marshmallow you have to create an AVD targeting 23 or lower , then data would appear.
Another approach is updating the SDK to ver 3.0 beta 2 on canary channel, although it's not stable but this problem is solved and you can access db on higher Apis.

Comment: Does that mean my database is created and I just can't view it with API 25?

Comment: Exactly.If you are using Android studio ver 2.?.?

Comment: Am using 2.3. I will try it out and let you know. Any other approach to create/view the DB with API 25?

Comment: I faced the same issue but found  just two ways ,updating to ver 3.0 or creating an AVD which targets Api < 23

Comment: I went ahead and fired an Insert query and then a select query. It seems my database was created already and I got the select query values. It's just that ADM doesn't show the database.

Comment: That's good news that you made sure db is created correctly.now all you have to do is creating an AVD which targets 23 or lower Api. After running your app on newly created device you would be able to see database from ADM.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon in the create query.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " (RecordingID TEXT PRIMARY KEY,RecordItemName TEXT,RecordFilePath TEXT,RecordFileDate TEXT);");
```

Comment: That didn't work. Even I don't this could be the issue as the database should have been created before this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database like this so we can create database on install of application.

```
public class DataBaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentinfo.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public static final String STUDENT_ID = "id";
    public static final String STUDENT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_NO = "number";
    public static final String STUDENT_CONTACT = "contact_number";


    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_NO + " TEXT," + STUDENT_CONTACT + " TEXT" + ")";



    public DataBaseHelp(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE OF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

[image: Go to device file explorer]

[image: data --> data --> [select your package name] --> databases]